# modify shortcuts.xml to run PHP pages at localhost in notepad++

Tags: localhost, wamp, notepad++

So I just changed my shortcuts.xml file so it can run a php file as localhost, and not the full path.

But my problem is that It cannot read the php files if they are in a folder in the WWW folder 
The Original path is

```
C:\wamp\www\basics\out.php
```

When I changed the shortcuts.xml file the output becomes

```
http://localhost/out.php
```

But I have every project in different folders.
Is there anyway I can change the xml file so the path is

```
http://localhost/ProjectX/out.phop
```

THis is how I wrote the shortcuts.xml

```
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="82">chrome &quot;http://localhost/$(FILE_NAME)&quot;</Command>
```

This is the Original

> chrome "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to solve this is to set up one shortcut for each folder.

```
chrome &quot;http://localhost/ProjectX/$(FILE_NAME)&quot;
```

If you have a lot of projects/folders this is not very nice but for a few it works.

Comment: Yes I Know it's exactly what I came up with. It probably doesn't work with an dynamic path. Thanks anyway